# How can i combine queries from different databases(DBeaver EE) in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, dbeaver

I just started using DBeaver EE for my work and this doesn't allow me to merge or combine queries from different databases. For example, if i want to find a set of unique customers in a time period and the first half of the time period is from one database and the rest is from the other. Is there a way to union both the databases and get a distinct on top?

Comment: Such a functionality in Db2 for LUW is called [Federation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=federation).

Comment: Depends on which __platform__ of Db2 you are using (Db2 for Z/OS,  Db2 for i-series,  Db2 for Linux/unix/windows/cloud).  Different approaches for different platforms. Always write your Db2 server platform in the question when asking for Db2-help - the answer depends on it, often.